# unable to create a project azure devops 2019 on premises

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I have azure DevOps server on-premises, and I want to create a new project but I can't. even though I'm using the admin account. I can create a new collection, but I can't create new projects, here's the log when I check it

```
++ Executing - Operation: ProjectCreate, Group: ProjectCreate.TfsTeamBuild
[09:35:38.947] +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[09:35:38.947] Executing step: Create the Team Project
[09:35:38.947]   Executing step: 'Create the Team Project' Build.CreateTeamProject (7 of 12)
[09:38:43.323]   [Error] The file exists.
[09:38:43.427]   System.IO.IOException: The file exists.
[09:38:43.427]      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
[09:38:43.427]      at System.IO.Path.InternalGetTempFileName(Boolean checkHost)
[09:38:43.427]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.ProcessTemplate.UpdateCachedProcessParameters(IVssRequestContext requestContext, VersionSpec versionSpec)
[09:38:43.427]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.TeamFoundationBuildService.AddProcessTemplates(IVssRequestContext requestContext, IList`1 processTemplates)
[09:38:43.427]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.TeamFoundationBuildService.CreateBuiltInProcessTemplates(IVssRequestContext requestContext, String teamProjectUri, Boolean isUpgrade)
[09:38:43.427]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.TeamFoundationBuildService.CreateTeamProject(IVssRequestContext requestContext, String projectUri, IList`1 permissions)
[09:38:43.427]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.Servicing.TFCollection.BuildStepPerformer.CreateTeamProject(ServicingContext servicingContext)
[09:38:43.427]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationStepPerformerBase.PerformHostStep(String servicingOperation, ServicingOperationTarget target, IServicingStep servicingStep, String stepData, ServicingContext servicingContext)
[09:38:43.427]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationStepPerformerBase.PerformStep(String servicingOperation, ServicingOperationTarget target, String stepType, String stepData, ServicingContext servicingContext)
[09:38:43.427]      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.ServicingStepDriver.PerformServicingStep(ServicingStep step, ServicingContext servicingContext, ServicingStepGroup group, ServicingOperation servicingOperation, Int32 stepNumber, Int32 totalSteps)
[09:38:43.427] Step failed: Create the Team Project. Execution time: 3 minutes and 4 seconds.
[09:38:43.427]   [StepDuration] 184.3850653
[09:38:43.427]   [GroupDuration] 184.4857136
[09:38:43.777]   [OperationDuration] 204.5521056
[09:38:43.787]   Clearing dictionary, removing all items
```

But there's no existing file the project name is unique. any kind of support it'll be appreciated thanks & regards

**edit:**
the steps I do to create a project: I provide the project name and the description then I click create project
[to create a project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxdLL.png)

Comment: if the question is referred to development ,then serverfault.com isnt the best place.  However the error tells you that a file already exists wherever/whatever you trying to do ...

Comment: thanks for your comment,
this is not about development, it is about Azure DevOps server management,
I cleared the %temp% file and created a new collection but still could not create project, I used different browsers, and the incognito mode but still facing the same issues, but there's no existing file anywhere since the collection is brand new.

Comment: have you tried a random name for testing ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
yes, I did, I tried random names, and even I created a new collection and tried to create a project with a random name. I tried to create the project using the rest API but still faced the same issue

Comment: what's the path that will be used? on what kind of devices

Comment: I don't understand what do u mean by path.
for the devices, I use a local server: azure DevOps server 2019 on-premises

Comment: if its using a local file, then the path is either fixed or known. what fits on your issue?

Comment: the file should be created in the temp folder but as I mentioned I cleared it already that the issue